# ranked preference matching in R

Tags: r, matching, ranking

I'm not sure how to best describe my problem, but I am working on a scheduling project. I have a data frame containing the professors, courses, and time slots as well as several columns each containing a randomly generated number. I'd like to use these random numbers to generate different schedule options.

This is what I have:

```
  Prof     Courses   Time      Option_1  Option_2
  John     Course A   Time 1   0.7765824 0.3102492
  John     Course A   Time 2   0.5636233 0.4839778
  John     Course B   Time 1   0.5814365 0.7282360
  John     Course B   Time 2   0.2623851 0.5198096
```

And, this is what I want:

```
  Prof     Courses   Time      Option_1  Option_2
  John     Course A   Time 1   1         0
  John     Course A   Time 2   0         1
  John     Course B   Time 1   0         1
  John     Course B   Time 2   1         0
```

For Option 1, 0.7765824 is the highest number, so it is changed to a one - meaning that courses will be taught in that time slot. The next highest number - for a course not scheduled and a time slot filled - is 0.2623851, so it is changed to a 1.

For Option 2, 0.7282360 is the highest number, so it changes to 1.Then, then 0.4839778 changes to 1, since it is the highest number for a course not scheduled and a time slot not filled.

The real data involves a couple hundred professors teaching varying numbers of courses and hundreds to options, so the solution needs to be able to work group_by() function (or something similar) and be flexible enough to account for professors teaching varying number of courses.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's the dput: `structure(list(Prof = c("John", "John", "John", "John"), Courses = c("Course A", 
"Course A", "Course B", "Course B"), Time = c("Time 1", "Time 2", 
"Time 1", "Time 2"), Option_1 = c(0.7765824, 0.5636233, 0.5814365, 
0.2623851), Option_2 = c(0.3102492, 0.4839778, 0.728236, 0.5198096
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))`

Comment: for option_1, if you use c(0,1,1,0), you get a higher sum of scores than using c(1,0,0,1). What are these randomly generated numbers? Are they indicating the preferences of students and you are trying to find the optimal schedule that maximize this score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop should take care of it on a per option basis, the `df` does get returned in a new order though.

```
df <- df[order(df$Option_1,decreasing =T),]
coursesdone <- c("FakeCourse")
timedone <- c("FakeTime")
for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Courses))){
    available <- df$Courses != coursesdone & df$Time != timedone
    df$Option_1[available][1] = 1
    df$Option_1[df$Courses == df$Courses[available][1] & df$Time != df$Time[available][1]] <- 0 
    coursesdone[i] <- as.character(df$Courses[available][1])
    timedone[i] <- as.character(df$Time[available][1])
}
```

but we can stack the loop for however many options you have

```
df <- df[order(df$Option_2,decreasing =T),]
coursesdone <- c("FakeCourse")
timedone <- c("FakeTime")
for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Courses))){
    available <- df$Courses != coursesdone & df$Time != timedone
    df$Option_2[available][1] = 1
    df$Option_2[df$Courses == df$Courses[available][1] & df$Time != df$Time[available][1]] <- 0 
    coursesdone[i] <- as.character(df$Courses[available][1])
    timedone[i] <- as.character(df$Time[available][1])
}
```

to get a final output (once both loops have been executed)

```
> df 
  Prof Courses  Time Option_1 Option_2
3 John CourseB Time1        0        1
4 John CourseB Time2        1        0
2 John CourseA Time2        0        1
1 John CourseA Time1        1        0
```